# money_format() expects parameter 2 to be double, string given

Tags: php, laravel

En la Siguiente expresión en la que quiero dar formato a unos valores:

```
@foreach($price_list as $price)
    $number = ($price->price_normal); 
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_ES'); 
    echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
@endfoerach
```

**Resultado:**

> money_format() expects parameter 2 to be double, string given.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

¿Esto se puede hacer directamente en el controlador de Laravel y traerlo a la vista ya con formato?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dar formato a campos de un modelo en `Laravel` se emplea [Accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators) es decir el típico *(get y set)* , así pues si desea dar formato de tipo `Moneda` la función que está empleando sería correcta pero debe tener en cuenta que dicha función no está disponible en algunos Sistemas Operativos.

En su lugar podría emplear [number_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) para dar el resultado que desea.

Para esto en su modelo definiría el *getter* , para este ejemplo usaré solo dos campos *nombre y precio*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre','precio'
];

/* después del get debe ir el nombre del campo seguido de Attribute*/
public function getPrecioAttribute($value) {
    return '$'.number_format($value, 2, ',', '');
}
```

Teniendo esto definido cada vez que quiera obtener el atributo de la clase aplicará el formato respectivo, desde la vista accedería normalmente.

```
@foreach ($productos as $element)
     <li><p>{{  $element->precio }}</p></li>
@endforeach
```

**PD:** Pueden haber mejores formas de presentar los datos en la vista

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones para asegurarte de que el contenido es numérico:

```
// Convertir usando la función floatval
$number = floatval($price->price_normal);

// Convertir de forma automática (cast)
(float) $number = $price->price_normal;
```

También se puede suponer que el número ya esté formateado, incluyendo separador de miles (,) y hay que eliminarlos con str_replace.